# Why is camera intent not returning a file path?

Tags: android, android-camera

I am starting up a camera intent with this code:

```
val takePictureIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
takePictureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
takePictureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
val file = viewModel.createImageFile(context, "somefile.jpg")
viewModel.destinationImageFile = file
val photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "${BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID}.provider", file)//"${applicationId}.provider"
takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri)
startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, TAKE_PICTURE_RESULT_CODE)
```

But when I receive and handle the intent it looks like this:
[image: image of result content]

Why am I not getting back the Url for where the image was saved?

Answer (score 2):

> Why am I not getting back the Url for where the image was saved?

Because it is not supposed to. The documentation does not say that `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` returns a `Uri`.

In your case, you are providing `EXTRA_OUTPUT`. In this case, `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` is supposed to return nothing (other than the result code). You know where the image is supposed to be: the value that you supplied for `EXTRA_OUTPUT`. So, look for the image there.

Answer (score 0):

You have it

```
val file = viewModel.createImageFile(context, "somefile.jpg")
```

get path with file val or if u want to get path from data in onActivityResult you may use this class

```
public class ImageUtils {

    /**
     * Get a file path from a Uri. This will get the the path for Storage Access
     * Framework Documents, as well as the _data field for the MediaStore and
     * other file-based ContentProviders.
     *
     * @param context The context.
     * @param uri The Uri to query.
     * @author paulburke
     */
    public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

        final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

        // DocumentProvider
        if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            // ExternalStorageProvider
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                }

                // TODO handle non-primary volumes
            }
            // DownloadsProvider
            else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
            }
            // MediaProvider
            else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }

                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
                        split[1]
                };

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
        }
        // MediaStore (and general)
        else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        }
        // File
        else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of the data column for this Uri. This is useful for
     * MediaStore Uris, and other file-based ContentProviders.
     *
     * @param context The context.
     * @param uri The Uri to query.
     * @param selection (Optional) Filter used in the query.
     * @param selectionArgs (Optional) Selection arguments used in the query.
     * @return The value of the _data column, which is typically a file path.
     */
    public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                       String[] selectionArgs) {

        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String column = "_data";
        final String[] projection = {
                column
        };

        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                    null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }


    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    public static long getImageId(Context context, String path) {
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media._ID};
        String where = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " =  ?";
        String[] whereArgs = {path};

        Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                projection,
                where,
                whereArgs,
                null);

        if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
            long id = c.getLong(0);
            c.close();
            return id;
        }

        return -1;
    }

    public static String getThumbnailPath(Context context, long id) {
        Cursor c = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.queryMiniThumbnail(
                context.getContentResolver(),
                id,
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND,
                null);

        if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
            String path = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA));
            c.close();
            return path;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

in onActivityResult you can use it

```
String picturePath =  ImageUtils.getPath(this, selectedImage);
```